Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
I am using a MacOS machine using zshell and have suddenly been unable to use virtualenvwrapper. This was after having to accept a new user agreement for Xcode. Now, when I load a new terminal, I get the following message:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.


This happened when I went to push something to my private git repository and got something like "Agreeing to the Xcode and Apple SDKs license requires admin privileges..." I followed its prompt and agreed.
My .zshrc file looks like this:
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin/python3:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/

export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/opt/homebrew/bin/python3' # (tested against the line below)
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3' # (tested against the line above)
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # (this seems to be causing the error on terminal launch)


and this is the current version/location of python on my machine:
~$ python --version 
Python 3.12.6

~$ which -a python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

Any idea why an Xcode update would prevent me on using my virtualenvwrapper and how to fix this? The source statement seems to be causing the message I get when I start a new terminal, but without it, I still cannot use virtualenvwrapper as I did just yesterday.
I have checked other similar questions, and have tried to follow them, but am still not getting it to work. I am a student so this has been stopping me from getting more of my work done. I swear this all worked yesterday until XCode decided to update!

I found a solution! After digging through a bunch of StackOverflow answers, I realized most solutions had everything in the usr/bin/ directories.
As a MacOS Homebrew user, I had a version of python installed in /opt/homebrew/bin/python3, where /opt/homebrew/bin/ also housed the location of my virtualenvwrapper.sh and  virtualenv.sh files.
Therefore, the solution became to overwrite the brew links to these installations. I did so by first trying to re-install the two packages:
brew install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Then overwriting the symlinks:
brew link --overwrite virtualenv
brew link --overwrite virtualenvwrapper 


This has (seemingly) fixed my issue.
